# get Quote Item ID from event checkout_cart_product_add_after not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer, quoteitem

I'm adding product to cart programatically in magento 2

> $this->cart->addProduct($product, ['product' => $product->getId(),
>   'qty' => '1']);

I want to get quote `item_id` using event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` But always return null.

My `events.xml` file here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="addCustomerOption" instance="Ciklum\CustomerAuth\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And Observer Class.

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    /* @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

    $product = $observer->getProduct();

    echo $item->getId();exit; // always return null

}
```

Note I'm adding product programatically. Not from Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by below code

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
$item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
echo $item->getId();exit;
```

Comment: did u check this one. I checked this one earlier its not working.

Comment: Yes above code is working

Comment: i already check its not working

Comment: I guess this keep happening. Looks like the QuoteItem is not properly loaded/passed and there is not ID, price, base_price etc. After adding the product again, the data is available. Magento 2.3.2. Take a look to this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18685

Answer (score 0):

You will not receive the item id from the event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` because the quote item is not created in the database until the same event is fully executed. So at that time there is no item id created. You can use other event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` for the same.